# Count Number of Pages per AGENDA- Text Mining in r

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining

I have to count the number of pages per AGENDA ITEM. I have extracted text from pdf document into a data frame, essentially one row of this data frame contains one page of text. This is how my data looks like:

```
mydf <- data.frame(text = c("AGENDA ITEM 1
        4", "This particular row contains a lot of text, really its all text present in one page", 
        "So ineffect, one page of text per row", "This is another page of text in this row", 
        "lets include another page for agenda 1", "AGENDA ITEM 2
        9",
        "now all the text in agenda 2 is included here","the 2nd page text of agenda 2", 
        "AGENDA ITEM 3
        12", "Now lets just add one row for this agenda, meaning it only has one page inside it"))
```

Under the AGENDA TEXT (Same row), the number is the page number and it's in the same row. To count the number of Pages per Agenda, I just need to count the Number of rows until the next AGENDA ITEM appears. Considering the above example the answer should be

```
AGENDA ITEM 1 = 4 Pages, AGENDA ITEM 2 = 2 Pages and AGENDA ITEM 3 = 1 Page.
```

How will I do this? 
I am fairly new to analysing text. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the pattern "AGENDA ITEM ##" does not appear within your normal text you may use the following approach using `grep()`. I hope this works for you.

```
#get all rownumbers of rows starting with the pattern
start_rows <- grep("AGENDA ITEM \\d+", mydf$text)

#get the end of each "AGENDA ITEM chapter"
#a chapter ends one line before the next chapter starts, hence, 
#-1 and offset -1 from startrows
#and the final chapter ends with the last line
end_rows <- c(start_rows[-1]-1
              ,length(mydf$text))

end_rows-start_rows
#[1] 4 2 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I just tested it on the whole document and it worked amazingly.

Comment: Depending on what your downstream tasks will be, you might also consider using `strsplit()` to split the lines at the desired pattern (output will be a list) and count the rows in each element, but I understood that you want to keep your orignal text as is. Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Sorry! I was not sure how to mark your answer as 'answered' since I am new here. I just googled it and it was just a matter of ticking the tick. Yes I want to keep the text as it is but thanks :)

Comment: No problem, and welcome to SO :-). Another hint, in case you plan to analyze very large text data sets and need more pattern matching, I recommend a look into the packages `stringr` and `stringi`, the first has very nice programming vocabulary whereas the latter is a bit more advanced and complicated at the first look but is faster in many cases - hence, have a look at thosee and select one depending on needs.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your guidance :). I'll look into these two packages as I do think that in future I will be doing more of NLP and working with textual documents.

Comment: Then some additional hints. In case you have not looked into [CRAN Task NLP](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NaturalLanguageProcessing.html), then have a look at the listed packages. If speed is an issue I recommend a look into `text2vec` and `tokenizers`. To avoid critique concerning opinion-based comments, I have done some case by case benchmarking and in most cases these packages were faster than others - again, it depends on the functionality you need and the style of programming you like.

Comment: Perfect Manuel, your a star!. No I did not come across the CRAN task NLP and it's very useful - a list of all packages in one location. At the moment speed is not an issue but when it becomes I will look into the text2vec and tokenizers package. Once again, thanks for your guidance. I'm happy I asked a question here and was answered by you with a lot more than just a answer :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` like this

```
mydf <- data.frame(text = c("AGENDA ITEM 1
                            4", "This particular row contains a lot of text, really its all text present in one page", 
                            "So ineffect, one page of text per row", "This is another page of text in this row", 
                            "lets include another page for agenda 1", "AGENDA ITEM 2
                            9",
                            "now all the text in agenda 2 is included here","the 2nd page text of agenda 2", 
                            "AGENDA ITEM 3
                            12", "Now lets just add one row for this agenda, meaning it only has one page inside it"))

lst <- as.character(mydf$text)
index <- grep(pattern = "AGENDA ITEM", lst)
index <- c(index,length(lst))

pages <- diff(index)
pages[1:length(pages)-1] <- pages[1:length(pages)-1] - 1
pages

[1] 4 2 1
```

Comment: Thanks Hardik, Just tried it and it worked really well. Thank you so much

Comment: I have tried a few times to up vote it, it changes the number 0 to 1 for a second and then the following message appears 'Thanks for the feedback!  Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score'